# Implement transport with different priorities in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have three suppliers in AnyLogic, each of which delivers to a storage. Now I want the goods to be delivered to the storage and forwarded from there to a work step. The problem here, however, is that only one work area is allowed to work at a time. So for the time being, goods should only be transferred from Storage1 to Delay1. This should be limited to 2 pieces. After 2 pieces have been transported, the path should be blocked and 2 should be transported from Storage2, then from Storage3 in exactly the same way. Then go back to Storage 1 and repeat the whole process. How can I implement this in AnyLogic? Thank you!

[Illustration of the current model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxKMg.png)

So far I've only managed to set the paths to hold by pressing a button. However, I would like to automate this and don't know how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to AnyLogic and SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Welcome again, happy to help